# what is the work done if force F= 3xyi-y^2 moves a particle in the xy plane from (0,0) to(1,2) along the parabola y=2x^2?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I know that work W=F.dl. But how can i apply this in above question? HOW CAN I FIND dl from the above question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is a math problem and is probably better suited for Mathematics SE. However, I will spare some tips on solving this problem:

- Parameterize the curve as l = (x(t),y(t)) and solve for dl. (hint: let one variable equal t and solve for the coordinate. You need x and y as functions of t, hence parameterization.)
- You need to input the parameterization into the force field function. Solve for F(x(t),y(t)).
- Solve the integral F(x(t),y(t)) dotted with dl, using appropriate limits of integration.